# InvalidCastException unhandled while updating gride view

Tags: gridview

Hi I am getting error `InvalidCastException unhandled` please help me to overcome with this problem.

`string att =` `((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;`

Comment: try to use FindControl with the ID instead of Controls[0]

Comment: Is this android? Please mention the technology in which you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

try to Use **FindControl**

```
 DropDownList idCombo = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("comboID");

 string att = idCombo.SelectedValue;
```